# As a US citizen programmer, what kinds of visas can I get to work abroad remotely for my US employer?

Tags: visas, international-travel, us-citizens, work, long-term

I am a programmer working for an employer in the US who is willing to let me work remotely from another country. I would like to travel abroad and visit different countries with my wife and kids. Tourist visas are easy to come by for short time periods, but we want to stay in each country for closer to a year and country hop for a few years, possibly in Europe, Asia, and Central and South America. Because of the extended stays, it's not clear to me what kinds of visas would allow me to do this. I'm not close to retirement age, so a retirement visa doesn't seem like a possibility.

- What type of visas would be best suited for this type of extended tourist type travel?
- Where can I find information about which countries offer extended tourist/visitor visas? or other visa related information for a large number of countries?
- Might it be feasible for me to set up a US LLC to obtain a Business visa to establish my business in a foreign country? If so, what sort of cost range would I expect for this type of visa?
- Does this plan sound feasible (from a visa perspective)? I don't hear of many people doing this, but that could be for a lot of reasons. Are there others that you know of who pull off something similar?

Comment: WRT the expat part of the question, consider posting on [International Man](https://www.internationalman.com/) or [InterNations](http://www.internations.org/) (if you already have an international presence).  You might also want to follow the [Expatriates proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates?referrer=pHo7j1-e9Kt9c2qQO4fLxA2).  In the meantime, I've also set up an Expat Q&A community for related questions; see my profile.

Comment: nilbus, it's completely different for every country.

Comment: @Joe This was a question about visas, not taxes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first identify the country in which you want to reside, and then learn its immigration laws. The IATA site referenced by Andra is not a good source of information, it may have enough for tourists and business travelers, but that's not what you're going to be. I've just checked it for a couple of combinations that I can relate to and it didn't provide any useful results.

You would also need to deal with taxes, and plan it accordingly. There are tax treaties with certain countries, but not with others, that reduce your tax burden there, and in the US. If there are no tax treaties, you will be subject to double taxation. The US treaties won't reduce your US taxes, but might help you reducing or eliminating your local taxes in that country.

You should *not* compare yourself to volunteering organizations such as the Peace Corps, as they work in an entirely different legal framework. What their members/volunteers can do - you are not necessarily able to (and most likely - cannot, in most places).

Specifically to your questions:

> What type of visas would be best suited for this type of extended tourist type travel?

This is **not** tourist type travel. You need a temp. resident/foreign worker visa, in most countries.

> Where can I find information about which countries offer extended tourist/visitor visas?

Embassies.

> Might it be feasible for me to set up a US LLC to obtain a Business visa to establish my business in a foreign country? If so, what sort of cost range would I expect for this type of visa?

Depends on the country, and you should consult an immigration attorney in that country. In your own country (the US) - this is not an option readily available for foreigners. Why would it be different elsewhere? My default assumption is that it wouldn't.

> Does this plan sound feasible (from a visa perspective)? I don't hear of many people doing this, but that could be for a lot of reasons. Are there others that you know of who pull off something similar?

Doesn't sound feasible to me.

Comment: I would appreciate the downvoter not to hide, and explain what it is he/she is disagreeing with.

Comment: I think you're right about having to look this up individually for different countries. Thanks for suggesting talking to those countries' embassies in the US - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: My downvote is because this is not a travel question. Answering just encourages people.

Comment: @DJClayworth agree

Comment: You've got the taxes the wrong way around there: you're first and foremost liable for taxes to the country you legally work in, and the US takes this into consideration when taxing you on top of that.  (Most countries, on the other hand, don't tax you at all on overseas income if you're no longer a resident.)

Comment: @jpatokal oh, but here's the nice part: the OP earns money in the US. His employer is US employer, his income is US income. From the host country perspective - you're right. They'll want priority on their share. But from the US perspective - its US income, and no foreign deduction will be allowed. That's why unless there's a treaty, the OP will almost certainly get taxed twice (and even with treaty he may get taxed more than he would have living in the same country as his employer). BTW: I have some experience here, I've got hit with double taxation myself.

Comment: Treaty benefit in this case is avoiding double taxation (there's always a provision that in no case the person would be taxed more than without the other country taxation). But without the treaty - even that is unavailable.

Comment: That's only if he stays as an employee, which would be stupid for all parties concerned.  The sane thing would be to "quit" (or take a sabbatical or whatever), set up/join a consulting company X in country Y, and then company X signs a deal with the original employer to provide consulting services (read: programming).  Ta-dah, OP's income is now entirely in country Y, and not the US.

Comment: @jpatokal I do have certain "official" knowledge on the US taxation. I've taken college classes, and passed several IRS licensing exams. So I do have the authority when I say what I say (although, disclaimer is in order, this is in no way tax advice). What you just described will dig the hole even deeper for the OP. It will definitely not help avoiding the double tax, but will definitely add *additional* tax liabilities and reporting for the CFC.

Comment: @jpatokal joining an *existing* company as a simple *employee* (as opposed to setting up a new one or becoming a partner/shareholder in an existing one) will help solving the problem by shifting it to the employer (the new one that is).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: if you're bona fide "living and working abroad", which also means paying local taxes, the first $91k of your income is tax-free as far as the IRS is concerned.  http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=108276,00.html  Your comment about "shifting the problem to the employer" is nonsensical though, since an American citizen's personal tax issues are completely irrelevant to a foreign company.

Comment: @jpatokal shifting the problem of US-sourced income taxation, I mean. Bona fide residency exclusion doesn't cover the US-sourced income.

Comment: @jpatokal and as a general point - US government is very aggressively attacking foreign tax shelters in their various shapes, including some of the schemes you've described. Unless the payment flows through an **unrelated** foreign employer, the US citizen working abroad for a US employer is in a tax nightmare. What people could do and get away with until recently, is no longer possible with the enactment of the new FATCA rules, and the punishments are severe.

Comment: "This is not tourist type travel." You have to be realistic.  Person X is Swedish, and is doing a contract for a Japanese company.  X happens to go to Australia for a long 3 or 6 months holiday.  Nobody in that triangle cares that X takes along a laptop and may do some typing now and then. It's **totally** OK to get a holiday visa to Australia in that circumstance. No need to mention you telecommute.  This is ubiquitous.  BUT in terms of the OP's question, since the OP is a *US* citizen, it's inconceivable the OP will save a penny of tax; there are no "tricks".

Comment: @jpatokal *"Ta-dah, OP's income is now entirely in country Y, and not the US"* .. um, the US authorities have thought of that.  It's a total, complete, non-starter.  Don't even bother.

Comment: @JoeBlow Read on: it's still non-US, the US just happens to tax it anyway if it exceeds the $91k threshold.